# What's my IP Address?

Tags: code-golf, internet

I'm surprised this hasn't come up in a challenge yet.

Output the IP address of the machine you're running on. You are required to output both the local and external IP addresses.

Local IP address, ie along the default format of 192.168.x.x

Public IP address can be verified by using google https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=hp&q=whats+my+ip

Output can be in any format. IPv4 or IPv6 or any mix of each is allowed, however they must be the only output. Code can be a full program or a function.

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply so shortest code wins.

[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

**EDIT:**
As per @Peter Taylor's comment, in the case where multiple of either type of address are present, you can choose to either output the first one, or as many as you can access. So long as at least one local and one public are present.

Comment: I think the `0/1` thing adds in unnecessary fluff to the challenge.

Comment: otherwise i thought it'd be too simple...

Comment: I agree there isn't much interest left in golfing an `if(x){X}else{Y}`, might as well ask to output both informations without input. As always, using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) is advised.

Comment: @Xynos It's not recommended to add fluff just to make the challenge harder. The difficulty of a challenge should come from the challenge itself, e.g. the 0/1 format isn't necessary and it really doesn't give a lot of golfing opportunities.

Comment: I'll change the challenge to output both as per @Aarons suggestion then :)

Comment: What is any format? Can the output contain garbage (like HTML tags etc.)? Can I output one in IPv6 and the other IPv4?

Comment: Ill accept one in either format v4 or v6 but other garbage is not allowed

Comment: This is underspecified. In particular, it doesn't clearly address cases where there are multiple local IP addresses and/or multiple public IP addresses. Furthermore, there's no reliable way of telling whether I have multiple public IP addresses, and if so what they are.

Comment: What if the host doesn't have any RFC 1918 addresses?  It looks like there's no reliable answer to this, except on machines that have at least one private network.

Comment: Machines don't have IP addresses. Network interfaces do. Fail.

Comment: ... and even one network interface can have multiple IP addresses.

Comment: The external IP address part is solved with a standard loophole by most answers.

Comment: What if we have multiple local Ip addresses? Output any one of them? Output all of them? Output a very specific one?

Comment: Actually, I don't see how you could solve half of this *without* [fetching from an external source](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062/29547), which is one of the standard loopholes you have expressly forbidden.

Comment: @TobySpeight, if you're not behind NAT, then your local and external addresses are the same.  This challenge is basically "output the address according to your network interface, and your address according to a remote server".

Comment: Surely it's 127.0.0.1...

Comment: Currently my answer is the accepted one even though there are shorter solutions, you should update the accepted answer..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Bash + [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) + [iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2), <s>54 50 49 48</s> 33 bytes

```
ip r g 1|awk '$0=$7'
curl eth0.me
```

Thanks @DomHastings for golfing off 1 byte!

Thanks @Sisyphus for coming up with a shorter URL!

Thanks @zeppelin for golfing off 9 bytes!

Comment: @DomHastings Your last golf attempts returns some garbage along with the ip address, at least on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: @Ferrybig Yeah, the `1/0` part outputs an error to STDERR, but that is ignored by default, if you get different output for `ip route` though, that could just be the version I was running on my machine. Shame!

Comment: The first line prints `1000` for me... 
`ip route get 1` output: https://ptpb.pw/pixx

Comment: When I run that code I get this output: `RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

Comment: You can use `ip r g  1` to save some bytes (at least with a Linux version of `ip`).

Comment: You can also optimize your AWK expression a bit: `awk 'NR<2&&$0=$7'`

Comment: @kasperd In that case probably all of the answers here fail.

Comment: If you mention curl in the header, you should mention ip as well. Also, what are the thingies over the numbers supposed to look like? I get dotted rectangles on my desktop, and barely noticeable tildes (crossed out 49 looks like regular 49) on my phone. A regular `<s>` would be more portable.

Comment: This [bash answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139921/17187) is only 24 bytes.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: But it doesn't work.. Though [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139626/48198) is shorter and works!

Answer (score 9):

## Bash <strike>37</strike> <strike>31</strike> 27 bytes

This is inspired by the [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139538/21461) by [Bruce Forte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48198/bruce-forte). That answer only works with IPv4 which means it doesn't work for me. I have rewritten it into a version that (only) works with IPv6:

```
ip r g b::|awk '$0=$9" "$9'
```

This is tested on Ubuntu 14.04.5 connected through PPPoE and since IPv6 is designed to be used without any NAT it will output the same IP address twice.

-6 bytes thanks to [zeppelin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61904/zeppelin),
-2 bytes thanks to [Ferrybig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10621/ferrybig),
-2 bytes thanks to [Markasoftware](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10973/markasoftware).

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, I had to change `'{print$11,$11}'` to `'{print$9,$9}'` to make the command work, your command returned 1024 2 times, Your command works on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 machine

Comment: @Ferrybig Probably depends on network configuration then. I tested this on a network where addresses are auto-configured from router advertisements.

Comment: For machines where the ip address is manually configured (static), `ip route` doesn't output the `proto ra` part, you could use this as a feature to golf your answer further

Comment: @Ferrybig At the moment I am pondering whether I can find a way to make it work in both cases without the size blowing up. Btw. on my 16.04.3 machine which received its configuration using router advertisements it says `proto static` not `proto ra`, though that difference doesn't matter to this code.

Comment: To golf it a bit, use `awk '$0=$9" "$9'` instead of `{print$11,$11}`. Many systems (including my Arch one) use the 9th word, so it's shorter than 11, and also using this syntax is smaller than print$9,$9

Comment: @Markasoftware Just tested my Pi and found there I had to use `$7`. So I have seen 7, 9, and 11 across the various devices on my network.

Answer (score 7):

## AutoIt, <s>56</s> 53 bytes

```
#include<Inet.au3>
ConsoleWrite(@IPAddress1&_GetIP())
```

[`@IPAddress1`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm) is a macro that returns

> IP address of first network adapter

[`_GetIP()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_GetIP.htm) returns

> the public IP address.

---

-3 bytes thanks to @mınxomaτ

Comment: Neat, a fellow AutoIt (not IT) -er. You can delete the spaces in this code.

Comment: @mınxomaτ Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

<s><sup>Mathematica has a builtin for everything</sup></s>

```
$MachineAddresses
```

[As described in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachineAddresses.html), this builtin command lists all IP addresses (both local and external) associated with your device.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about external addresses.

Comment: If this command also lists the ipv6 address, then you can say the ipv6 address is the expected result

Comment: This produces a list of several IP addresses for me, but none of them seem to be my external address; I may not be interpreting things correctly, though. I can get my external IP address from something like `WolframAlpha["ip address", {{"IPAddress:InternetData", 1}, "ComputableData"}][[1,2]]` but I don't know how to get at that more directly.

Comment: @MarkS. That is odd; I get my external IP address when I run the command (the last entry seems to be it). This command won't work on Wolfram Sandbox, though. Perhaps this is a bug; what OS and Mathematica version are you using?

Comment: @JungHwanMin 11.1.1.0 Student Edition gives me 6 things that I assume are IPv6, then 192.168.0.104, and three addresses beginning with 169.254. But my external address begins with 69.

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>196</s> <s>194</s> <s>188</s> 163 bytes

```c#
namespace System.Net.Sockets{using Linq;_=>Dns.GetHostEntry("").AddressList.First(i=>(int)i.AddressFamily==2)+" "+new WebClient().DownloadString("http://eth0.me")}
```

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Xynos.*
*Saved 25 bytes thanks to @Nick.*

Full/Formatted Version:

```c#
namespace System.Net.Sockets
{
    using Linq;

    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Func<object, string> f = _ =>
                Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
                    .AddressList
                    .First(i => (int)i.AddressFamily == 2) + " " + new WebClient().DownloadString("http://eth0.me");

            Console.WriteLine(f(null));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cant you save two bytes by removing the whitespace around the == ?

Comment: @Xynos Of course, didn't realise I hadn't removed it.

Comment: The golfed version does not compile and is not a standalone function.  It doesn't seem fair to mix a standalone function with the shortcut of using the Sockets namespace, so I'd suggest picking one option and going with it.  That said, you can save some bytes by casting `i.AddressFamily` to `int` instead of casting `2` to `AddressFamily`, and you can replace `Dns.GetHostName()` with the empty string.

Comment: @Nick I will try that when I get a chance and the `namespace` trick is fairly common for C#. If you think it shouldn't be allowed you can post on meta about it but at the moment it is fair game and a neat trick in shortening `using`s.

Answer (score 6):

### PowerShell v4+, <strike>40</strike> 36 bytes

```
NetIPAddress|% IPA*
iwr eth0.me|% C*
```

*(Only works on Server 2012 R2 or above, or Windows 8.1 or above. Doesn't work on TIO.)*

Does exactly what it says on the tin. Gets the local network IP addresses and selects just the `IPA`ddress portion thereof (e.g., filters out the subnet mask, the gateway, etc.).

The second is a `Invoke-WebRequest` to `http://eth0.me` which simply gets the `C`ontent thereof; i.e., just the public IP address.

---

Ungolfed version:

```
(Get-NetIPAddress).IPAddress
(Invoke-WebRequest eth0.me).content
```

Comment: An anonymous user suggests removing `Get-`

Comment: @StepHen Indeed. Works great.

Answer (score 4):

#Unix Shell + [stunclient](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/stunclient.1.html), 40 bytes

```
stunclient stun.vo.lu|cut -d: -f2|sed 1d
```

Makes use of a [STUN protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389):

> Session Traversal Utilities for NAT (STUN) is a protocol that serves
> as a tool for other protocols in dealing with Network Address
> Translator (NAT) traversal.  It can be used by an endpoint to
> determine the IP address and port allocated to it by a NAT

The STUN server name is from the [Public STUN server list](https://gist.github.com/mondain/b0ec1cf5f60ae726202e).

The output format is:

```
 LOCAL IPV4 ADDRESS
 PUBLIC IPV4 ADDRESS
```

Note that both lines will be indented with a single space, but I believe this does not break the output rules as written.

Sample output:

```
  192.168.1.100    
  209.85.233.147
```

Answer (score 4):

## curl (bash one-liner): 27 bytes

```
curl -w%{local_ip} eth0.me
```

The result is printed on `stdout` and looks like this:

```
1.2.3.4
192.168.0.10
# no trailing newline, use "curl -w%{local_ip}\\n eth0.me" for it
```

`curl` should be at least of version 7.29.0 (from Feb 6, 2013).

The answer is based on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139538/66016.

Answer (score 4):

### Go, MacOS only, 10 bytes

In macOS this [killswitch](https://vpn-kill-switch.com/) could be used, it can print current private active IP and public IP:

```
$ killswitch 
Interface  MAC address         IP
en1        bc:34:36:d2:81:ba   192.168.2.10

Public IP address: 179.43.176.99

No VPN interface found, verify VPN is connected
```

This is not a built-in tool but tries to simplify the process of finding the proper IP's.

The output could get by using commands like:

```
$ route get 0.0.0.0

$ ifconfig | pcregrep -M -o '^[^\t:]+:([^\n]|\n\t)*status: active'

$ networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder

$ scutil --dns
```

Public IP:

```
$ dig o-o.myaddr.l.google.com @ns.google.com txt +short
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to PPCG! This question is tagged [tag:code-golf]. Could you provide golfed code with a language and a byte count?

Answer (score 3):

**Python 3, <strike>124</strike> 133 bytes**

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import socket
a=urlopen('http://eth0.me').read()
b=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print a,b
```

Comment: Don't you also need to `print a,b`? Interestingly, this does output two IPs on my system (Win7), but neither one of them is my actual local IP address. `b` is actually the IP of a virtual adapter and not my *Local Area Connection*.

Comment: Arguably though, that is still a *local Ip address*. I left a comment on the Question to ask for clarification on that.

Comment: @Octopus you're right about printing, updated

Comment: In a suggested edit, @David suggested this: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYtBDkAwEEX3TmHXTkgJO7dRJtrQzqTGwulLsLF6@e/n8SmOYp@zD0xJyp2mFaUuj7Rt3nYFJx9Ff8vcJMaolRPhoWlQXGsCKjAJx1lD9eZmuQ/axZ5xDKj/8lEAkPMF "Python 3 – Try It Online") ([Review here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/43751))

Comment: You can print without () in Python 3??

Answer (score 3):

**PowerShell v3+ (alternative answer for windows 7+)**

```
((ipconfig) -match "v4").split(":")[1]
Invoke-RestMethod eth0.me
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: You can remove the spaces surrounding `-match` to save a couple bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + Awk + Curl, 43 bytes

using only built in tools for Mac and Linux

```bash
ifconfig|awk '/bro/{print $2}';curl eth0.me
```

Comment: *bash you mean .

Comment: bash + awk +  curl

Comment: i edited the question to say bash since it works on my linux laptop not just macos

Comment: thx, I improved since bash is a shell per se (should work on tcsh, sh and any other shell), you need to have ifconfig, awk and curl also

Comment: This isn't "MacOS/Linux", it's Bash. Just mark it as such.

Comment: Your code produce literally no output when I run it on my machine.

Comment: `grep "bro"|awk '{print $2}'` → `awk '/bro/{print$2}'`

Comment: This assumes that the interface is eth0, which is not always the case.

Comment: @manatwork thx, nice job!

Comment: @Liam eth0.me is a url which show yours external IP, has nothing to do with the interface name

Comment: Oh good to know, I apologize

Comment: Only shows my external IP on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

### Node.js (JavaScript) <s>224</s> <s>223</s> <s>194</s> <s>175</s> <s>173</s> 130 bytes

```
r=require,l=console.log,r('dns').lookup(r('os').hostname(),(a,b)=>l(b));r('http').get('http://eth0.me',a=>a.on('data',c=>l(c+"")))
```

Ungolfed version:

```
require('dns').lookup(require('os').hostname(), (err, loc, fam) => console.log(loc));
require('http').get('http://eth0.me', res => {
    res.on('data', chunk => console.log(chunk + ""));
});
```

---

- *Saved 1 byte* (due to unnecessary semicolon).
- *Saved 29 bytes thanks to @AndrewLi* (used arrow functions for shorter code).
- *Saved 19 bytes thanks to @MiniGod* (used `.get()` instead of `.request()` - `.end();` removed).
- *Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Zacharý* (parentheses not needed around a lone parameter of an arrow function).
- *Saved 43 bytes thanks to @Birjolaxew* (stored `require` and `console.log` in single-letter variables, passed url directly to `require('http').get`, logged output directly from `data` event).

Comment: Can't you use arrow functions for shorter code?

Comment: @AndrewLi Great suggestion, thanks. :)

Comment: You can use `.get()` instead of `.request()`. Then you also don't need the `.end();`.

Comment: You can also chain the `.on()` calls.

Comment: You don't need parens around a lone parameter of an arrow function. (`(a)=>` => `a=>`), IIRC.

Comment: MiniGod and @Zacharý, updated, thanks :)

Comment: An FYI: The Node REPL automatically imports `os`, `http` and `dns`. I'm not sure Node.js also includes the REPL in the scope of PPCG, but that could get rid of your `require` calls.

Comment: @AndrewLi Hmm, the problem is that when the code is run in the REPL, it prints out extra info (e.g. the request information), which is prohibited in the question. I could add extra code to hide this output, but it might counteract the reduction of bytes which result from leaving out the `require` calls, so I'll leave it for now. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: You can save quite a few bytes by storing `require` and `console.log` in single-letter variables. You can also pass the string directly to `require('http').get` (if you prepend the protocol), saving another few bytes. You *could* also log the output in the `data` event, but I'm not sure if that's consistent. [Shortest variant I could come up with](https://goo.gl/Q9j1xY)

Comment: @Birjolaxew That's great, thanks :) Good point about the `data` event - it seems to work for now, but if it doesn't in the future, I'll revert it.

Comment: Much [shorter version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151171/17187), if it's OK to use external "What is my IP address" services.

Answer (score 2):

**Python 2.7.13 128 bytes**

```
print __import__("urllib").urlopen("http://eth0.me").read(),__import__("socket").gethostbyname(__import__("socket").getfqdn())
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, <s>142</s>, <s>140</s>, 137 bytes

```r
library(magrittr);system("ipconfig",int=T)%>%regmatches(.,regexpr("v4.+",.))%>%{a=nchar(.);substr(.,a-14,a)};readLines("http://eth0.me")
```

Tested on win10 and R (3.4.1).
Thanks for @Bruce-Forte for short URL.

Ungolfed version:

```r
library(magrittr)
system("ipconfig",int=T) %>% 
     regmatches(.,regexpr("v4.+",.)) %>% 
      {a <- nchar(.)
       substr(., a - 14, a)}
readLines("http://eth0.me")
```

Comment: Down to 120 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBDsIgEEDRqzSzggitJl1JewOXXmDEsbAAG5gaiPHsyO4vXn5qrayJtoBsHWVRF51rZgoC/G7f8eU3UD7yepeqMyp7EvCZxxOoKqX54rDoIVqHSRRp8vHI3EuhvswK5c8kwufNx34Gx7xfp4nYncdAIFv7Aw "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @BLT nice solution. You can save 3 bytes, by replacing `a <- nchar(x)` with `a=nchar(x)`

Comment: @AndruisZ thanks, but it's really your solution -- I just de-magrittr'd it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Windows' Batch File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), 116 bytes

```batch
@for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "v4"')do @echo%%b
@powershell -Command "(iwr eth0.me).content"
```

The first line iterates through the results of running `ipconfig` and gets your local IPv4 address.

For the public IP part, I had to steal a bit from the marvelous [Powershell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139556/66000) because, as far as I know, there is no way to get the machine's public IP using solely batch scripting.

We start with an `@` sign, to suppress echoing the prompt (`C:\...\path>`), then run the Powershell command `Invoke-WebRequest` (with its alias, `iwr`) and extract the `content` part of that.

I experimented with *not* using `(...).content` and, instead, only running the command and extracting the actual information from the complete output, using batch. But that proved to be way longer than this solution, so I kept it.

Tested on Windows 10.0.15063.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + Curl, 24 bytes

```
hostname -i;curl eth0.me
```

Comment: This doesn't work.. From the man page: "*This option enumerates all configured addresses on all network interfaces. [...] Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output."*

Comment: Doesn't **-I** (capital) have a different use than **-i** (lowercase). The bit you quoted was from the **-I** section.

Comment: True, sorry about that. But even worse it says "*Avoid using this option*", either way this doesn't work (at least on my machines)..

Comment: Right, admittedly I did not read the full documentation before posting. Oddly enough it seems to work fine on a few of my machines. But this inconsistency would make this solution unreliable at best.

Answer (score 1):

## MS-SQL, 59 bytes

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 local_net_address
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

Returns the client-facing IP address of the SQL instance executing the query.

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 58 Bytes

***Whoops, does not handle local address - fix in progress***

> ***Note:***
>   Uses reference to
>
> `Microsoft Internet Controls`

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs the user's IP address via an Internet Explorer window

```vb
Set i=New InternetExplorer:i.Visible=1:i.Navigate"eth0.me"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash — 29 bytes (linux)

```
curl ipinfo.io/ip
hostname -i
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 97 bytes

```python
from socket import*
from requests import*
gethostbyname(gethostname()),get('http://eth0.me').text
```

returns tuple with `('LOCAL_IP', 'PUBLIC_IP')`, as apparently

```python
x = 2,3
type(x)
>>> tuple
```

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 103 bytes

```python
from socket import*
from requests import*
gethostbyname(gethostname()),get('http://api.ipify.org').text
```

ditto, read below.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 107 bytes

First solution

```python
from socket import*
from requests import*
gethostbyname(gethostname())+" "+get('http://api.ipify.org').text
```

The `+" "+` part is for joining strings together.

If you leave just the `+` sign, 103 bytes are possible, but would yield the strings without spaces which could lead to results like this `"5.5.5.111222.222.222.222"` and they should still be readable, as there are only 3 digits at max in every ip part.

But there are edge cases like `"5.5.5.11111.222.222.222"` where it would be impossible to distinguish the local vs public part.

<strike>Other possible savings are in the public ip grabber tool. I used this site, as it was the first thing I found on the Internet and it returns html with just text in it, which is super nice.</strike> I saw other people using `http://eth0.me`, but it doesn't load for me on my machine and my antivirus has it blacklisted, thus Python raises a `ConnectionError`. It loads through Tor though, so I don't know whether I should use it.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 101 bytes

```python
from socket import*
from requests import*
gethostbyname(gethostname())+" "+get('http://eth0.me').text
```